# Get specific index from MultiIndex of Pandas data frame as list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, multi-index

I want to to get a specific index of a Pandas data frame with a `MultiIndex` as a list.

Given the example

```
import pandas as pd; import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.set_index(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
```

in which `df` is defined as

```
     C  D
A B
3 4  2  4
4 1  2  2
2 4  3  2
4 1  3  1
3 4  0  3
```

I want to extract

```
[4 1 4 1 4]
```

which corresponds to the second index `B`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `get_level_values`

```
df.index.get_level_values(level=1).tolist()
Out[1040]: [4, 1, 4, 1, 4]
```

Or `reset_index`

```
df.reset_index(level=1).B.tolist()
Out[1041]: [4, 1, 4, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses stacking through [`np.stack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) and slicing:

```
np.stack(df.index.values, axis=0)[:,1]
```